# yacc outputs unexpected results

Tags: c++, c++11, yacc

I have this rule in yacc file and a separate c++ file for the action of the rule.
But the output is not expected as shown with the print statement below .This is the rule in parser.y :

```
RecordItem : IdentifierList ':' TypeDenoter   
             {  
               char * result = declareRecordItem ($1 , $3); 
               $$ = result;
               printf(" >>> inside RecordItem >>  : %s\n",result);
             }
           ;
```

and this is the function 'declareRecordItem' in main.cpp file :

```
char* declareRecordItem( std::vector<char* >* varList , char* type){
     string stm = " ";
     string identifier;
     for(int i=0 ; i < varList-> size() ; i++) 
     {
       identifier= string((*varList)[i]) ; 
       symtab[identifier] = string(type);
       stm = stm + " " + string(type);
     }
   char * result =  (char*)stm.c_str();
   printf(">>> inside declareRecordItem >>  : %s\n",result);

  return result  ; 
}
```

The output in declareRecordItem function is correct but when it returns to the RecordItem rule, it does not produce any thing or sometimes strange symbols are printed as shown. Any idea !.

```
>>> inside declareRecordItem >>  :   i32 i32
 >>> inside RecordItem >>  :
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside `declareRecordItem`, you create a local variable `stm` of type `std::string`, and then return the value: `(char*)stm.c_str()`;

However, `stm` ceases to exist as soon as `declareRecordItem` returns, and the pointer returned by `stm.c_str()` is no longer valid. It is quite possible that the memory it now points to has been reused to hold some other object.

So if you want to retain the value of the string, you should either

- return the `std::string` itself, relying on RVO for efficiency, or
- create and return a dynamic object (i.e. `new std::string()`), or
- make a C-style copy of the string buffer (i.e. `strdup(stm.c_str())`)

In both the latter two cases, you will need to manually free the copy once you are finished with it. In the first case, you will still need to make a copy of the underlying C string if you need to retain a C string.

Mixing C and C++ string handling is confusing and leads to cluttered code. If you are going to use C++, I recommend using `std::string*` throughout, although you end up with the same manual memory management regime as you would have with C style strings. For compilers and other applications with symbol tables, a good compromise is to put the string into the symbol table (or a map of immutable symbol names) as soon as possible, even in the lexical scanner, and then pass around references to the symbols (or interned names). Then you can free the entire repository of  retained strings at the end of the compilation.

Comment: If I create a dynamic object , it will be of pointer type, i.e string * stm = new new std::string(); . But how to append to it like that inside for loop ?.

Comment: `*stm = *stm + " " + ...` or just `*stm += " " + ...`

Comment: One final question please. how can I convert string* to char* ?

Comment: By making a copy of the C string returned by c_str, as indicated in my answer.

Comment: Yes strdup works fine .. thanks but how can I  free the variable if I need to return it .. I need to use it in the other file i.e char * result = declareRecordItem ($1 , $3);

Comment: @leenarose: Precisely. You can't free it until you are finished with it. That was the problem with your original solution: you were letting C++ free (destruct) the string before you were done with it. So when you return the pointer, you are also passing on the responsibility to free the storage.